# Динамическое выделение памяти для виджета верхнего уровня

Tags: c++, qt

Начал изучение *Qt* и на определенном этапе встал вопрос с освобождением памяти, вот пример кода:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Spin();
    return a.exec();
}

void Spin()
{
    QSpinBox *psb = new QSpinBox();
    psb->show();
}
```

Верно ли так выделять память для виджета верхнего уровня в локальной функции и нигде далее не освобождать память для него?

Comment: Нужно задать родителя. В текущем случае будет утечка памяти.

Comment: Спасибо, а то вопрос покоя весь день не дает)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QObject` в своём деструкторе выполняет освобождение памяти дочерних элементов. Т.е. элементов, у которых `Parent` установлен на уничтожаемый элемент. Например:

```
QObject* p = new QObject();
QObject* c1 = new QObject(p);
QObject* c2 = new QObject();
c2->setParent(p);

delete p; // Вызовет уничтожение c2, c1, p
```

Чуть более подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

---

В вашем случае при выходе из функции `Spin` память, адресуемая указателем `psb` будет утеряна, т.е. произойдёт утёчка.

Самый простой способ избежать утечки - избавиться от `Spin` вовсе и использовать практически [канонический](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners#Our_first_window) *hello world*:

```
int main()
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   QSpinBox psb;
   psb.show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

Замечу, что в этом случае используется создание `QSpinBox` на стеке, т.е. деструктор будет вызван автоматически.

Если требуется оставить выделение памяти в куче, то нужно любым доступным образом обеспечить освобождение ресурсов `psb` при завершении программы.

Один из возможных способов - обернуть его в умный указатель типа `QSharedPointer` и вернуть наружу из функции:

```
QSharedPointer<QSpinBox> Spin()
{
    QSharedPointer<QSpinBox> psb(new QSpinBox());
    psb->show();
    return psb;
}
```

Код `main` будет выглядеть так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto s = Spin();
    return a.exec();
}
```

В этом случае при завершении `main` будет выполнено уничтожение `s`, который хранит в себе `psb`.

Comment: А разве qApp может быть родителем, по крайней мере вызывает ошибку, на несоответствие типа

Comment: @Funnyjoco действительно. Нужен `QWidget`, а не `QObject`. Предложил альтернативный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Comment: @Funnyjoco заходите ещё :)

Comment: Добавлю по первому примеру, что официальная документация не рекомендует прямой вызов delete для указателей на QObject, для этих целей есть функция deleteLater

Comment: @BeardedBeaver ссылочку можете дать на такую рекомендацию?

Comment: Пожалуйста http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject Здесь говорится про удаление объектов, живущих в отдельном потоке, но вообще говоря, события в очереди могут быть и при жизни объекта в основном потоке.